Is there a reason for the lack of vector's (and other sequential containers such as deque) constructor that moves an element to perfom one less copy?
Inspecting the constructor std::vector::vector( size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );(ref), we can read that it:

Constructs a vector with count copies of elements with value value.

I think I see a missed opportunity for optimization, albeit a very minor one. An introduction of std::vector::vector( size_type count, T&& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() ); would allow for count - 1 copies and 1 move, which would most likely be more performant. This constructor could first move from value into the vector's buffer and copy from it, or start copying and replace a final copy with a move.
Apart from nobody has yet proposed it and this seems like an insanely minor gain for introducing yet another constructor, are there any valid reasons why such optimization is absent from constructor overloads?

Seems to me like your observation ("... this seems like an insanely minor gain for ...") is spot-on.

fwiw, same for std::fill and std::fill_n

I'd go even further: this seems like an insanely minor gain for breaking backward compatibility by changing behaviour of already existing programs. Standard committee doesn't want to break compatibility even for big improvements (std::regex...), they wouldn't consider this idea for one second.

@Yksisarvinen This wouldn't be an incompatible change. You just add an overload that takes rvalue reference. Or at least not any more breaking than adding such overloads to other functions were.

I don't know, the reasons you disregard seems pretty valid. Especially since a proposal is not just "writing a paper", but an entire process involving interaction with the committee and protecting the new cog in vector's overload resolution. A lot of effort for... one less potential copy?

"This constructor could first move from value into the vector's buffer and copy from it, or start copying and replace a final copy with a move." That's two different obvious implementations. Now 50% of people are going to assume the wrong behaviour. Maybe not detrimentally most of the time, but sometimes that's going to be a bug

@user17732522 It changes behaviour of existing programs. Code that would invoke const T& overload in older standard would suddenly start invoking T&& overload in new standard. I don't think this happened ever after C++11?

@Yksisarvinen std::string::substr had a &&-qualified version added in C++23 with a similar effect; can't think of another post-C++11 example at the spot

From a user perspective I would be very confused from the interface. My first impression would be "It tries to move the same value multiple times?" One may even try to use it with a class which has no copy constructor but only a move constructor and may get confusing compiler errors. For the existing vector constructor it is obvious that it makes copies.

Constructing the vector as per this proposal would be essentially the same net effect (assuming count is non-zero) as a two-liner  std::vector<T> somevec(count - 1, some_t); somevec.push_back(some_t);   (since C++11, push_back() has an overload that accepts a T &&).      Performance wise, the difference would be insignificant.  Developer wise, the two-liner would give less of the head-scratching mentioned by Thibe (other than people wondering why that has been preferred over std::vector<T> somevec(count, some_t);)
